# Unable to access mounted GCS bucket from within Vertex AI Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I've mounted a GCS bucket within a Vertex AI notebook using the following commands:

```
MY_BUCKET=cloud-ai-platform-a013866a-a18a-470f-9d35-f485abb17e82

cd ~/

mkdir -p gcs

gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --rename-dir-limit=100 --disable-http2 --max-conns-per-host=100 $MY_BUCKET "/home/jupyter/gcs"
```

Within the terminal I can do `ls gcs/` and get a list of the directories within the mounted bucket (`test  uncorrupted_split_heightmaps`), but when I try to access these directories from within a Jupyter Notebook, they cannot be found.

Running the following code within a Jupyter Notebook:

```
import os
print(os.listdir('../gcs'))
```

gives the output:

```
[]
```

instead of the expected output:

```
[test, uncorrupted_split_heightmaps]
```

And

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
idg = ImageDataGenerator()
heightmap_iterator = idg.flow_from_directory('../gcs/test', 
                                             target_size = (256, 256), 
                                             batch_size = 8,
                                             color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                             classes = [''])
```

gives the output:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

instead of the expected output:

```
Found 732458 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

How can I access the mounted GCS bucket from within a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Enabling debug logs in gcsfuse will provide insights into what is happening when os.listdir('../gcs') is run. Can you please share the logs using following cmd: "gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --rename-dir-limit=100 --disable-http2 --max-conns-per-host=100 --debug_gcs --debug_fs --debug_fuse --log-format 'text' --log-file log.txt $MY_BUCKET "/home/jupyter/gcs"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the user managed notebook instead of managed notebook. That resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Alishan, I just wanted to say, you are my hero. It took nearly 24 hours for me to find this, but it works perfectly. If I could give you 1000 upvotes I would. Thank you so much for this simple fix. I wish all the tutorials would have mentioned this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Alishan's answer is right. I just wanted to add that if you are using managed notebooks, you might no longer need gcsfuse since you can already view and access the cloud storage buckets using the "Browse GCS" button found on the far left as mentioned in the documentation[1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/cloud-storage)

You can simply path to the objects in those buckets (e.g. images) in Jupyter notebook using the cloud storage pathing (gs://{name of bucket}/{directory}). In your example, the path might be 'gs://cloud-ai-platform-a013866a-a18a-470f-9d35-f485abb17e82/gcs/test'